# Chrome shortcut to open new tab in same tab group

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions

I want to open a new tab to the current tab group I'm in. the hectic way is to `right click the tab inside the tab group -> add tab to the right`

Is there any chrome shortcut available to shorten the clicks?

Comment: link for google explanation (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10483214?hl=en)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

#### Updated:

Thanks to [@Vitaly Strikanov's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1713982/167207), I got to know that shortcut of `New Tab to the Right` can be set from system preferences.

**Native Solution for Mac Users:**

Follow these steps to set the keyboard shortcut for `New Tab to the Right` menu option.

- Open System Preferences (not chrome settings but Operating system's preferences)
- Select Keyboard -> select `Shortcuts` tab
- Select `App Shortcuts` from left panel
- Click on <kbd>+</kbd> icon to add new shortcut
- From the `Application` list, select `Google Chrome` and in the `Menu Title` write this exactly same text `New Tab to the Right`
- Now in the Keyboard shortcut field, enter whichever shortcut you want to set, and press `Add`

Bingo!!

#### Old Answer

So, I found one of the possible solution is to use the extension to accomplish this task.

**Extension:**

> [New tab in group keyboard shortcut](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-in-group-keyboard/hodhmojdnjljopdihkoniodkacnpimjf)
>
> **This extension can read your browsing history**

This extension provides exactly what I needed. the extension sets the shortcut to open the new tab in same tab group.

Comment: I swear this use to be a native browser setting (i.e. didn't require an extension).

Comment: If you want to _replace_ the behaviour of `⌘T`, then you must also set a tab shortcut in system preferences for `New Tab`

Comment: The New Tab in Group Keyboard Shortcut chrome extension has been removed from the Chrome Web Store, but the new answer works perfectly.

Comment: It does not work on my MAC chrome....cmd+T still opens tab on the right globally instead of inside group

Comment: @Travis You have to set a custom shortcut with the same menu command title ("New Tab to the Right") and that custom shortcut will open a tab in the same tab group. Cmd+T's functionality will not be changed.

Comment: I had this solution working. However it stopped working randomly today. Not sure what went wrong.

Comment: For those who would prefer an opinionated approach, use Cmd + Opt + T. Worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

**[This](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-adjacent-tab/fommpldicogfgegfpcoibmhkbbdpodjg)** chrome extension adds a `New tab to the right` (which automatically adds the tab to your current group) by the shortcut that you set for it.

So you can set it to `Ctrl`+`T` to overwrite the default behavior of chrome.

Comment: Since the other comment's suggested extension doesn't exist anymore this one is a good alternative

Comment: This extension seems trustworthy as it extension requires no special permissions and is "featured" in the Google Chrome web store.

Answer (score 7):

"New tab" extension is malware. If you are using chrome on macbook you can change the shortcut in keyboard settings and set "⌘T" for "New Tab to the Right" and also set "⌘⌃⌥T", for example, to "New Tab". And it will work better.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Vitaly Strikanov thanks for drawing my attention. I've updated my answer with detailed steps how to set shortcut of 'New Tab to the Right' option.

Answer (score 0):

Being a non mac-er @Keval Langalia's answer doesn't work for me, so for any other windows users I recommend the [Vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium) browser extension which adds a tonne of Vim based shortcuts for browser navigation.

Specifically in this case press `t` to create a new tab to the right of the current tab.